# Calculation based on custom formula, stored in a db table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with custom functions (function name and list of parameters) and use it for calculation of a percentage of a cost for a product. I need this done is SQL (SQL Server 2008).

This is the table to store custom functions

```
CREATE TABLE #tCustomFormula (customformula_id int, customfunction varchar(50), customparameters varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #tCustomFormula(customformula_id, customfunction, customparameters)
SELECT  1, 'xpCalcPercentage', 'customer_id,product_id,costperiod,productdate'
-- xpCalcPercentage is custom formula to calculate cost of a product
DROP TABLE #tCustomFormula
```

The calculation is done in stored procedure, where this table is queried with supplied customformula_id and list of parameters to stored function.

For example:

```
exec spExecCustomFormula 
   1,   -- custom formula id from the table above
  '1,22,888,''2015-01-01''' -- parameters
```

OR, to match to a list of arguments in the table

```
exec spExecCustomFormula 
   1,   -- custom formula id from the table above
  'customer_id=1,product_id=22,costperiod=888,productdate=''2015-01-01'''  -- parameters
```

What would be the best way to define this stored procedure? Basically, I need to match list of parameters to stored procedure to the customparameters field from table #tCustomFormula, construct the executeSQL string and using dynamic SQL, execute it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gena

=========================================================================

Answer (score 2):

Neither is particularly good, as you need to parse a string into a set of values, which SQL isn't very good at.

You seem to be asking about your attempted solution rather than the problem itself, i.e. [the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you add some information about the broader picture, why are you trying to do this in the first place?